# Create a utc date in vb.net to set in mongodb

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm having a bit of trouble with the mongodb c# driver, in that it seems to be converting all my dates to a UTC form.

I have

```
Dim cDate as Date
Dim year as integer = 2012
Dim month as integer = 12
Dim day as integer = 21
cDate = New Date(year, month, day)
```

However putting it into a mongodb database via the C# driver seems to convert it to UTC so all of a sudden its a different day now because its now `11:00 PM 20th December 2012`. Not exactly what I wanted!

Is there a way I can create the `New Date(year, month, date` such that its an UTC mode to begin with? So if i did `cDate.utcNow` I would get the same thing as cDate, in essence cDate.utcNow = cDate?

I have tried all sorts of stuff with the driver only to run into a brick wall such as using the `DateTimeSerializationOptions.Defaults` to no avail nothing happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your date as a UTC date, just specify the Kind parameter in the constructor along with the hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
cDate = New Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```